# How safely free /boot directory with broken apt-get package manager

Tags: boot, apt

I have a production vm U16.04 LTS which have broken apt-get and full `/boot` directory with various kernels.

```
apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-138 linux-headers-4.4.0-138-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-139 linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-141 linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-142 linux-headers-4.4.0-142-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-145 linux-headers-4.4.0-145-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-148 linux-headers-4.4.0-148-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-150 linux-headers-4.4.0-150-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-157 linux-headers-4.4.0-157-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic linux-image-4.4.0-142-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-145-generic linux-image-4.4.0-148-generic linux-image-4.4.0-150-generic linux-image-4.4.0-157-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-142-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-145-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-148-generic
  linux-modules-4.4.0-150-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-157-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-145-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-148-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-150-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-157-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-171 linux-headers-4.4.0-171-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-4.4.0-157-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic linux-image-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-157-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-171-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-171-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
Recommended packages:
  thermald
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-171 linux-headers-4.4.0-171-generic linux-image-4.4.0-157-generic linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic
  linux-modules-4.4.0-157-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-171-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-171-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
3 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 199 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 66.3 MB/85.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 369 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-4.4.0-171-generic amd64 4.4.0-171.200 [12.0 MB]
Get:2 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic amd64 4.4.0-171.200 [6,938 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-171-generic amd64 4.4.0-171.200 [36.6 MB]
Get:4 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 4.4.0.171.179 [1,790 B]
Get:5 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 4.4.0.171.179 [2,442 B]
Get:6 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-171 all 4.4.0-171.200 [10.0 MB]
Get:7 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-171-generic amd64 4.4.0-171.200 [798 kB]
Get:8 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.4.0.171.179 [2,282 B]
Fetched 66.3 MB in 1s (36.3 MB/s)                
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-4.4.0-171-generic.
(Reading database ... 415318 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-4.4.0-171-generic_4.4.0-171.200_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.4.0-171-generic (4.4.0-171.200) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-4.4.0-171-generic_4.4.0-171.200_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-171-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-171-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic_4.4.0-171.200_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic (4.4.0-171.200) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic_4.4.0-171.200_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-171-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-171-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

cd /boot && ls

abi-4.4.0-138-generic     config-4.4.0-154-generic      retpoline-4.4.0-138-generic   System.map-4.4.0-154-generic
abi-4.4.0-139-generic     grub                          retpoline-4.4.0-139-generic   vmlinuz-4.4.0-138-generic
abi-4.4.0-141-generic     initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic  retpoline-4.4.0-141-generic   vmlinuz-4.4.0-139-generic
abi-4.4.0-142-generic     initrd.img-4.4.0-139-generic  retpoline-4.4.0-142-generic   vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
config-4.4.0-138-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-141-generic  System.map-4.4.0-138-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-142-generic
config-4.4.0-139-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-142-generic  System.map-4.4.0-139-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-143-generic
config-4.4.0-141-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-143-generic  System.map-4.4.0-141-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-145-generic
config-4.4.0-142-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-145-generic  System.map-4.4.0-142-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-148-generic
config-4.4.0-143-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-148-generic  System.map-4.4.0-143-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-150-generic
config-4.4.0-145-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-150-generic  System.map-4.4.0-145-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-151-generic
config-4.4.0-148-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-151-generic  System.map-4.4.0-148-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-154-generic
config-4.4.0-150-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-154-generic  System.map-4.4.0-150-generic
config-4.4.0-151-generic  lost+found                    System.map-4.4.0-151-generic

uname -r
4.4.0-143-generic

df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  1.3G   12G  11% /run
/dev/md2        1.8T  714G  953G  43% /
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        488M  486M     0 100% /boot
/dev/sdc1       1.8T   68M  1.7T   1% /var/lib/mysql-extra-disk
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/111
```

I don't want to use any `rm` command if it's not safe. Any help appreciated.

Edit:

Removed:

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm abi-4.4.0-138-generic
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm abi-4.4.0-139-generic
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm initrd.img-4.4.0-139-generic
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm retpoline-4.4.0-138-generic
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm retpoline-4.4.0-139-generic
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm System.map-4.4.0-138-generic
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm System.map-4.4.0-139-generic
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm vmlinuz-4.4.0-138-generic
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-no-hwe /boot # rm vmlinuz-4.4.0-139-generic
```

and `apt-get install -f` worked. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up old unneeded kernel versions ?

Comment: Yes. - apt-get autoremove -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.

Comment: No it's not helping. I tried to delete one config file from /boot dir, but no space was freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which kernel version you're using with `uname -a`, then remove all config-*, initrd-*, System.map-* and config-* files from the kernels that you're not using, just to be sure, left one version behind (ie. if `uname -a` returns something like: `4.4.0-169-generic`, leave the files `4.4.0-166` and newer versions). Then, just run

```
apt -y autoremove
```

And you're good to go. If you don't wanna remove any files, you can also just move the `/boot` files somewhere else.

I use this procedure on all my 350 servers and it's pretty safe.

Comment: apt dosen't work. You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.

Comment: The reason apt doesn't work is because the `/boot` partition is full. Once you remove these files I've told you, probably it'll.

Comment: if you rm the files it does not free the space.